# What is the difference between installation of Julia then Atom and installation of JuliaPro?

Tags: installation, julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

I have a few questions about approach for installation of Julia.
1) Julia installation then Atom. 
2) JuliaPro installation.

Both approaches seem to result in having Julia on Atom Editor. Juno seems to come along with installation process and first run.

What would be big difference between two approaches? Does JuliaPro include extra packages that are preinstalled?

What might be disadvantages for not using JuliaPro?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

JuliaPro comes with a lot of packages installed. Juno through its normal installation comes bare, but you can add the packages with `Pkg.add`. JuliaPro has an easy download for MKL-support and easy GPL-free versions, but with standard Julia it requires building from source. JuliaPro has a version with enterprise support, while standard Julia does not. Basically, if you want an easy installation with a bunch of standard stuff or have some enterprise needs, then JuliaPro can be a good option. I personally prefer the freedom of the standard installation.

Comment: I appreciate it.